# How do I overload shared methods on non-instance types using extensions?

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods, overloading

By non-instance types I mean types which do not expose a public constructor, for lack of a better term.

I want to extend the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class with an overload of `ToString()` that takes a parameter of type `Char`, representing a value delimiter.

Why? By default, the `ToString()` call returns a string representation of a byte array, delimited by dash symbols. The signature does not allow you to specify a different delimiter, which I find very unfortunate.

Now because this is not an instance type, or maybe because I'm overloading a shared method,  I'm having a hard time finding the proper syntax to define my extension method.

What am I doing wrong here, causing the overloads to not show up in IntelliSense:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module BitConverterExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToString(ByVal converter As BitConverter, ByVal value() As Byte, ByVal delimiter As Char) As String
        Return BitConverterExtensions.ToString(converter, value, 0, value.Length, delimiter)
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToString(ByVal converter As BitConverter, ByVal value() As Byte, ByVal startIndex As Integer, ByVal delimiter As Char) As String
        Return BitConverterExtensions.ToString(converter, value, startIndex, value.Length, delimiter)
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToString(ByVal converter As BitConverter, ByVal value() As Byte, ByVal startIndex As Integer, ByVal length As Integer, ByVal delimiter As Char) As String
        Dim bytes As String = BitConverter.ToString(value, startIndex, length)
        Return bytes.Replace("-"c, delimiter)
    End Function

End Module
```

Or is it simply not possible to extend shared methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to introduce an overload of a method on a `shared / static` type.  Extension methods are feature whose usage is driven by instances of a type not the type itself.

Comment: Hmmm... that's what I thought but couldn't really find any useful information on the subject. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: So the proper way to do it is to turn these extension methods into normal methods, then call them directly?

Comment: @StevenDotNet yes that is the best approach.  Or another way is to create another type which offers up it's own methods and uses `BitConverter` as the primary implementation mechanism.  Then pass around instances of that type with the custom methods

Comment: I think I'll go with the second approach. Using modules doesn't feel right. :D